# Simple way to embed a QDialog into a QWidget

Tags: qt, dialog, qt4, pyqt, qdialog

I have been searching for a simple way to embed `QDialog` instances in a `QWidget`, but all I found used OpenGL or some rather complex stuff to achieve that. Actually, all the examples I found tried to achieve many more things than simply embed the `QDialog`. So, I am wondering: is there a simple and clean way to embed a `QDialog` in a `QWidget`?

P.S.: I tagged [pyqt](/questions/tagged/pyqt) since it's what I'm using, but I will of course accept c++ answers :)

Here is a [screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cupr.png) of the piece of software I have to port and for which I kind of need such a feature.

Comment: QDialog should not be embedded into QWidget. Did you read its documentation? "A dialog window is a top-level window mostly used for short-term tasks and brief communications with the user." it says. Why do you need such unusual task? Maybe you should just use another widget class.

Comment: @Morwenn That example is to embed interactive `QDialog`s into an OpenGL viewport - it is nothing like what you are asking.  This sounds like an XY problem, can tell us what you are actually trying to achieve - perhaps with a picture of something similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `QMdiArea`.

```
widget = QWidget()
mdiarea = QMdiArea() 
layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
layout.addWidget(mdiarea)
d = QInputDialog()
d.setLabelText("test2")
d.setInputMode(QInputDialog.TextInput)
w = mdiarea.addSubWindow(d)
w.show()
widget.show()
```

Answer (score 7):

```
myDialog->setWindowFlags(Qt::Widget); // to embed dialog as a simple widget
```