# Adding a description label to native QFileDialog

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qfiledialog

I want a description text(Qlabel) to be added to the native QFileDialog just like this [eclipse browse funtionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eLXs.jpg). Though we can add widgets by subclassing and adding to the default layout it works only if DontUseNativeDialog is set. But I want this to be added to the native dialog itself. Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible, but not directly using Qt. You'll have to integrate the native dialog yourself into a `QWidget`, and this will be different on each platform.

Comment: @KubaOber Can you please tell a bit more about this just for Mac? Is it something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163585/simple-way-to-embed-a-qdialog-into-a-qwidget

Comment: No, the question you refer to is unrelated. You can read how to encapsulate the native `NSView` in a `QWidget`, and then you can add anything else to it that you wish.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be a separate `QLabel`, but you can set the dialog title text to be a description.  I'm not sure how it appears on macs though (like it does in that eclipse dialog).

```
QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(parent, 'This is a description')
```